# git pull whackiness and can't delete remote branch

Tags: git

I keep running git pull and it keeps spitting out the same stuff like this

```
Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$ git pull
        From github.com:OrderlyHealth/orderly
        - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/asyncreview_Declan/CleanupReadAPI
        - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/asyncreview_Declan/DataApiClientRemoved
        - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/asyncreview_Declan/LinkAPIToProviderService
        - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/asyncreview_Declan/LinkingReadApi
        - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/asyncreview_Declan/MultiStreamAndWeirdJsonError
        - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/asyncreview_Declan/MultiStreaming
        - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/asyncreview_Declan/MultiStreamingFinished
        - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/asyncreview_Declan/RefactoringIntToLong
```

and I keep trying to delete branches but that's not working saying they don't exist.  I end up in a loop.  I even did a git fetch --prune from another post and git branch -r still lists branches that are probably deleted or at least when I delete them, it says they don't exist.

```
        Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$ ls -la .git/refs/remotes/origin/
        total 16
        drwxr-xr-x  4 dean  staff  128 Jun  3 13:40 .
        drwxr-xr-x  3 dean  staff   96 Jan 30 10:59 ..
        -rw-r--r--  1 dean  staff   32 Jan 30 10:59 HEAD
        -rw-r--r--  1 dean  staff   41 Jun  3 13:25 master
```

I try deleting a branch that says it exists

```
        Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$ git branch -r | grep asyncreview_Declan/CleanupReadAPI
        origin/asyncreview_Declan/CleanupReadAPI
        Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$
        Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$
        Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$ git push origin --delete asyncreview_Declan/CleanupReadAPI
        error: unable to delete 'asyncreview_Declan/CleanupReadAPI': remote ref does not exist
        error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:OrderlyHealth/orderly.git'
```

Comment: That's definitely odd; but names can be hidden in `.git/packed-refs` rather than spread out through the `.git/refs/**/*` hierarchy. The thing is, if `git fetch --prune` deleted them, they should have been deleted from the packed-refs file. Is it possible your Git directory is being managed by something like DropBox that keeps putting back the wrong packed-refs file?

Comment: i figured it out @torek I don't understand how.  We are ALL on MAC computers not windows but the rest of the git pull had a bunch of 'added' branches ALL with the same name but different case.  I had to delete ALL these 'added' branches that are never listed in git branch -r (only the deleted ones are listed with git branch -r which is ironic considering they don't exist and git won't let me delete them).  I still don't know how one person on our team did this with 10 or so branches on MacOS (our intern too...lol )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181179/git-pull-whackiness-and-cant-delete-remote-branch?noredirect=1#comment110018417_62181179) I will put in this answer.

The standard MacOS file system setup also does case-folding, like Windows. That is, if you create a file `ReadMe.txt` and try to open `README.TXT`, you get the same file. This affects *some* Git refs: specifically, the ones that are unpacked into individual files. It does not affect the remaining Git refs. The results can be a bit bizarre. However, the really odd thing is if you got the above repeatedly. If you only saw it once, that was Git sort of self-correcting.

As for how someone created them on GitHub, that's easy enough. When you run `git push` you can specify, to the other Git, what name(s) you want them to create or update. For instance, `git push origin master:newbranch` creates a branch named `newbranch` in the other Git—the one over at GitHub—using the same hash ID stored in your own branch name `branch`. Note that *your* branch name never even goes over to GitHub: they only see the branch name you ask *them* to create or update, in this case `newbranch`, and a hash ID.

GitHub servers run Linux and store names in a form in which uppercase and lowercase are entirely different, so *they* can have a `master` and a `Master`, for instance, which your Git will try to store as your `origin/master` *and* your `origin/Master`.  This works on your Mac when the refs are packed but doesn't work right when they're unpacked: you get *either* `origin/master` *or* `origin/Master`, but not both. If someone subsequently deletes the bogus `Master` on GitHub, your `git fetch --prune` will delete your `origin/Master`. If the refs were unpacked, this winds up deleting both `origin/master` and `origin/Master` since they both occupy one file.  A subsequent `git fetch` restores the missing `origin/master`, after which all is good.

Exactly what command(s) the person who created the wrong-case-name branches used are not possible to say; we only know the after-effects.